# Ajax in timer is affecting my server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using ajax so that i can read the content of a file from my server .I am calling a function where ajax is , in a timer.And this is affecting my server .It is crashing.If this is the correct way to do it , what's wrong?
Please give a few sugestions,because i don't know what its problem is.

I am calling first the function:"function(ctrl)".

```
function get(ctrl){
    var content;
        content=ctrl.id; 

        var getTextUpdate= setInterval(function () {
                    readdocument();
        }, 1200);

}

function readdocument() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                            document.getElementById("area").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                } 
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../user/test/read-text.php?user="+content,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

*Here it is the read-text.php  file:*

```
<?php
    $rec_user=$_GET['user'];
    echo($rec_user);
    $chat = fopen($rec_user.".txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($chat,filesize($rec_user.".txt"));
    fclose($chat);
?>
```

Comment: Why not using jquery or some already built in Js framework for ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, you are not waiting for the response to get over. So over the time, you are sending request after request. This is going to use up all memory in due time. So first wait for the response before sending the next request.

How about this ?

```
function loadXMLDoc(ctrl) {
    var content=ctrl.id; 
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "../user/test/read-text.php?user="+content;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("area").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
                setTimeout(loadXMLDoc(), 1200); //call the function again
            } else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                console.log('There was an error 400');
            } else {
                console.log('something else other than 200 was returned');
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};

loadXMLDoc(ctrl);
```

Comment: :while reading you're post i observed something, and i dont get it.What's content?You wrote something like this:"setTimeout(content(), 1200); //call the function again".Its a function?.And one more thing.Because you removed the function get(ctrl), do i have to call then the function loadXMLDoc?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Its not `content`, its `loadXMLDoc`. Yes now instead of `get(ctrl)`, you should now use the function `loadXMLDoc`. However you can rename the function according to your naming convention.